# $\iint (x+y)e^{xy} dA$ . where A is region enclosed by $x-y = 1$, $x-y=4$, $xy = 1$, $xy=2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Find the integral $\iint (x+y)e^{xy} dA$ . where A is region enclosed by $x-y = 1$, $x-y=4$, $xy = 1$, $xy=2$

So I tried the following substitution: 
$$u = xy$$ $$v = x-y$$

And want to find the partial derivatives of $x$ and $y$ w.r.t. $u$ and $v$.

However I am unable to isolate the partials as only functions of $u$ and $v$
For example for $dx/dv$ I get $1/(1+ u/x^2)$

I am unsure of how to proceed from this point.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation you chose is easy to invert:

$y=u/x$ and $v=x-u/x$ or $x^2-vx-u=0$ that can be solved for $x$: $x=\dfrac{v\pm\sqrt{v^2+4u}}{2}$. The for $y$: $y=\dfrac{-v\pm\sqrt{v^2+4u}}{2}$

From here, the partial derivatives can be explicitly calculated for you to compute the surface element.

Comment: In this case, since I am only looking for the region in the first quadrant, I have to select x and y such that they can't be negative, but I tried calculating the jacobian and I get 0, is there a better transformation I could select?

Comment: I get $1/\sqrt{v^2+4u}$ for the jacobian determinant, not zero, and the integral simplifies a lot.

Comment: yes I see my mistake, Thank you!